# Como buscar valores em pascal

Tags: procedure, pascal

eu estou montando um programa aqui em Pascal, onde eu tenho um registro com 3 posições, cada uma com nome, idade e peso.
Também tenho um procedimento chamado consulta, que vai me permitir buscar um nome cadastrado, e retornar suas idade e peso.
O meu problema é justamente esse, como eu faço para buscar esse nome? Tem que usar for? Tem que criar uma nova array? Me deem uma luz :D

Caso queira ver o programa, segue abaixo:

```pascal
Program Pzim ;

var opc, num: integer;
    esc: char;
    cad:array[1..3] of record
        nome: string[30];
        idade: integer;
        peso: real;
    end;

procedure menu;
begin
    writeln;
    writeln('1. Cadastro');
    writeln('2. Consulta');
    writeln('3. Exclusao');
    writeln('4. Sair');
    writeln;
    write('Opcao: ');
    readln(opc);
    writeln;
end;

procedure cadastro;
begin
     while (esc <> 'n') do
    begin
        writeln('Digite o seu nome:');
        readln(cad[num].nome);
        writeln('Digite a sua idade:');
        readln(cad[num].idade);
        writeln('Digite o seu peso:');
        readln(cad[num].peso);
        writeln('Cadastro concluído. Gostaria de realizar outro? (s: sim/n: nao)');
        readln(esc);
        num:=num+1;
    end;

    if (num>3) then
    begin
        writeln('Você só pode fazer 3 cadastros!');
        menu;
    end;

    menu;
end;

procedure consulta;
begin
    while (esc<>'n') do
    begin
        writeln('Digite o nome do usuário cadastrado:')
        readln();


Begin
num:=1;
menu;

if opc=1 then
    begin
    cadastro;
    end;

End.
```

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa criar um array para recuperar esses valores pela chave do array.

Imagine que você tem idade é peso. Então basicamente você precisar dar um "id" para seu array.

Exemplo.

```
variável Pessoa = array[2];
variável DadosPessoa = array[2];
```

A posição 1  do array Pessoa recebe o id da pessoa(nome ou número) e a posição 2 recebe outro array contendo DadosPessoa.

Assim ao chamar a posição 1 do array você pode recuperar sua idade e peso.

Dei um exemplo simples em pseudocódigo mas acho que você pegou a ideia.

Answer (score 0):

Na pesquisa por nome, pegue o nome digitado coloque em uma variável depois crie um 
`for` para listar todos os elementos, dentro dele insira com um `if` que verifica se nome é igual ao item atual do registro. Lembre que será necessário uma contador

Answer (score 0):

```
procedure consulta;
var nome_consulta:string; i:Integer;
begin
    while (esc<>'n') do
    begin
        writeln('Digite o nome do usuário cadastrado:')
        readln(nome_consulta);
        for i:=1 to num do
        begin
           if trim(cad[num].nome) = trim(nome_consulta) then
           begin
               writeln(cad[num].nome);
               writeln(cad[num].idade);
               writeln(cad[num].peso);
           end;
         end;
    end;
end;
```